# how do I solve this create-react-app problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have bought create react app template which is (https://reactify.theironnetwork.org/) , after installing all packages , it gives *Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled*, when typed `npm start`. what can i do?

Comment: `experimental syntax 'jsx'`. I wouldn't say jsx is experimental these days, are you using an old version of node / editor, or something??

Comment: my node version is 13.14.0, and my editor is pycharm professional which is up to date, I have launched one project using this template a month ago, now i gave a try to use it again but it's giving an error above

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your `package.json` file for your `start` script. It normally runs with `npm run start` but check to see that is indeed the script to start your app.